# Mac Anaconda OpenCV when deploys USB Webcam VideoCapture(1).read() always outputs (False, None)

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, face-detection

I am using MAC M1 and install OpenCV through Anaconda. I am writing sth like this:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while cam.isOpened():
    print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
    ret, img = cam.read()
    print(ret)
    print(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

But it turns out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hw/Desktop/Coding/Machine Learning/OpenCVFaceDetectionArduino/Model/Recognizer.py", line 41, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

The whole program works well with computer's own internal webcam but when I connect to a HIKVISION webcam it would report an error.

Please help me out... I think that is the problem of the computer's driver... I am debugging for a long time but still cannot find a solution.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error is due to the image not being loaded properly. Have you tried seeing those images using cv2.imread() function? You cannot colorcvt without the image being loaded properly.

Edit: You said the code works well on the internal webcam but not on the external one. If you can cant load a single image then i would assume its a driver fault

Comment: If it is a driver issue, is it because of something related to ffmpeg?  I found solution in the internet and it seemed that many of them were just changing ffmpeg settings but I am not sure how to set that in Mac M1